# Isses with code to produce Schelling segregation model in python

Tags: python

My homework assignment was to code the Schelling segregation model in Python. First, I was to use a random number generator to place two groups of agents into the environment; then, I was to determine if the agents were unhappy, move them, count each, and provide a percentage. Then, I was to increase the number of groups to see what would happen.  I was able to get the code to run but output seems to be  incorrect. Below is the output which just copies the same result i.e. for the changes and those unhappy.

**Number of Groups in this ABM 2.00%**

```
Iteration 1: 167 changes, 167 unhappy agents (22.27% of total)
Iteration 2: 55 changes, 55 unhappy agents (7.33% of total)
Iteration 3: 37 changes, 37 unhappy agents (4.93% of total)
Iteration 4: 13 changes, 13 unhappy agents (1.73% of total)
Iteration 5: 4 changes, 4 unhappy agents (0.53% of total)
Iteration 6: 1 changes, 1 unhappy agents (0.13% of total)
Iteration 7: 1 changes, 1 unhappy agents (0.13% of total)
Iteration 8: 0 changes, 0 unhappy agents (0.00% of total)
```

The Model has reached equilibrium. No more changes can occur

**Number of Groups in this ABM 3.00%**

```
Iteration 1: 283 changes, 283 unhappy agents (37.73% of total)
Iteration 2: 131 changes, 131 unhappy agents (17.47% of total)
Iteration 3: 72 changes, 72 unhappy agents (9.60% of total)
Iteration 4: 48 changes, 48 unhappy agents (6.40% of total)
Iteration 5: 32 changes, 32 unhappy agents (4.27% of total)
Iteration 6: 28 changes, 28 unhappy agents (3.73% of total)
Iteration 7: 14 changes, 14 unhappy agents (1.87% of total)
Iteration 8: 17 changes, 17 unhappy agents (2.27% of total)
Iteration 9: 11 changes, 11 unhappy agents (1.47% of total)
Iteration 10: 9 changes, 9 unhappy agents (1.20% of total)
Iteration 11: 8 changes, 8 unhappy agents (1.07% of total)
Iteration 12: 3 changes, 3 unhappy agents (0.40% of total)
Iteration 13: 3 changes, 3 unhappy agents (0.40% of total)
Iteration 14: 1 changes, 1 unhappy agents (0.13% of total)
Iteration 15: 0 changes, 0 unhappy agents (0.00% of total)
```

The Model has reached equilibrium. No more changes can occur

I created the code using a random number generator via import random and used 2 arrays, one for the agents when the model first setup the matrix and then the second to help track the changes when an agent moved or did not move.

```
import random

class Schelling:
    #this method assigns the values to be used for the model
    def __init__(self, width, height,similarity_threshold, number_of_iterations, group):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.similarity_threshold = similarity_threshold
        self.number_of_iterations = number_of_iterations
        self.different = group
        self.empty_houses = []
        self.agents = {}
        self.n_empty = int((1 - similarity_threshold) * width * height)

    #this method populates the matrix or neighborhood  via an array
    def populate(self):
        # these next 4 lines randomly populates and determines which houses are occupied and 
        # which houses are empty and which members of what group live in what house
        self.all_houses = [(x, y) for x in range(self.width) for y in range(self.height)]
        random.shuffle(self.all_houses)
        self.empty_houses = self.all_houses[:self.n_empty]
        self.remaining_houses = self.all_houses[self.n_empty:]
        houses_by_difference = [self.remaining_houses[i::self.different] for i in range(self.different)]

        for i in range(self.different):
            # create agents for each different person
            self.agents.update(dict(zip(houses_by_difference[i], [i + 1] * len(houses_by_difference[i]))))

    # this method helps to determine which occupants are unhappy counts them or what group the belong to
    def is_unsatisfied(self, x, y):
        group = self.agents[(x, y)]
        count_similar = 0
        count_different = 0

        for i in range(max(0, x - 1), min(self.width, x + 2)):
            for j in range(max(0, y - 1), min(self.height, y + 2)):
                if (i, j) != (x, y):
                    if (i, j) not in self.empty_houses:
                        if self.agents[(i, j)] == group:
                            count_similar += 1
                        else:
                            count_different += 1

        if count_similar + count_different == 0:
            return False
        return count_similar / (count_similar + count_different) < self.similarity_threshold
    # This method updates the array with agetns as they move around 
    def update(self):
        for i in range(self.number_of_iterations):
            self.old_agents = dict(self.agents)
            n_changes = 0
            n_unhappy = 0

            for agent in self.old_agents:
                if self.is_unsatisfied(agent[0], agent[1]):
                    n_unhappy += 1
                    agent_different= self.agents[agent]
                    empty_house = random.choice(self.empty_houses)
                    self.agents[empty_house] = agent_different
                    del self.agents[agent]
                    self.empty_houses.remove(empty_house)
                    self.empty_houses.append(agent)
                    n_changes += 1
#this section prints out the results of each run.
            unhappy_percentage = (n_unhappy / len(self.agents)) * 100
            print(f"Iteration {i + 1}: {n_changes} changes, {n_unhappy} unhappy agents "
                  f"({unhappy_percentage:.2f}% of total)")

            if n_changes == 0:
                print("The Model has reached equilibrium. No more changes can occur")
                break

# main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    width = 50
    height = 50
    similarity_threshold = 0.3
    number_of_iterations = 100
    group = 2
    
    print(f"Number of Groups in this ABM {group:.2f}%")
    model = Schelling(width, height, similarity_threshold, number_of_iterations, group)
    model.populate()
    model.update()
    print()

    group = 3
    print(f"Number of Groups in this ABM {group:.2f}%")
    model = Schelling(width, height, similarity_threshold, number_of_iterations, group)
    model.populate()
    model.update()
    print()
```

**Several questions:**

1. are the values of moving correct - I can't seem to figure out where in the code to help determine a total.
2. if the values are wrong, I believe the issue is in the for loops found in the update method.

I apologize if the code is off but I am new to this blog and am still learning all the ins and outs.

Comment: Why do you suspect the output is incorrect? Perhaps you might try to visualize each step to see what is going on.